# php if id==0 not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

im trying to do a simple car search with 3 select boxes ,the problem is want to display all cars when the 3 select values are 0 :
Only this part is not working :

```
 if($fabricante_id==0 || $modelo_id==0 || $combustivel_id==0){
    $filtros="";
    }
```

Full code :

```
    $fabricante_id=isset($_GET['fabricante_id'])?(int)$_GET['fabricante_id']:"0";
    $modelo_id=isset($_GET['modelo_id'])?(int)$_GET['modelo_id']:"0";
    $combustivel_id=isset($_GET['combustivel_id'])?(int)$_GET['combustivel_id']:"0";
    $filtros=NULL;
if($fabricante_id==0 || $modelo_id==0 || $combustivel_id==0){
    $filtros="";
    }    
  if($fabricante_id!=0 || $modelo_id!=0 || $combustivel_id!=0){
    if($fabricante_id!=0){
        $filtros=" where auto_fabricante='{$fabricante_id}' ";
    }
    if($modelo_id!=0){
        if($filtros){
            //$filtros= $filtros ." AND auto_modelo='{$modelo_id}' "; 
            $filtros.=" AND auto_modelo='{$modelo_id}' ";
        }else{
            $filtros="where auto_modelo='{$modelo_id}' ";
        }
    }
    if($combustivel_id!=0){
        if($filtros){
            //$filtros= $filtros ." AND auto_modelo='{$modelo_id}' "; 
            $filtros.=" AND auto_combustivel='{$combustivel_id}' ";
        }else{
            $filtros=" where auto_combustivel='{$combustivel_id}' ";
        }
    }

    $sql="SELECT * 
    FROM automoveis 
    {$filtros} ";
```

Answer (score 1):

The and operator in php is &&, not ||, you need to change it to:

```
 if($fabricante_id==0 && $modelo_id==0 && $combustivel_id==0){
    $filtros="";
    }
```

Comment: The OP also should be using the else operator instead of trying to do the opposite condition right after.

Comment: "*doesnt work either*" is such a helpful phrase here on stackoverflow.